# OSGI Blueprint Conditional Reference (ServiceMix)

Tags: reference, apache-servicemix, blueprint-osgi

I have two beans, `b1` and `b2`, and a boolean property `myFlag`.  Both `b1` and `b2` need to be constructed as they are used in different parts of the application.  The class hierarchies of `b1` and `b2` are as follows:

```
interface MyFirstInterface { ... }

class B1Class implements MyFirstInterface { ... }

interface MySecondInterface extends MyFirstInterface { ... }

class B2Class implements MySecondInterface { ... }
```

In my first blueprint file, I have:

```
<service id="b1" interface="com.company.MyFirstInterface">
    <bean class="com.company.B1Class" />
</service>
<service id="b2" interface="com.company.MySecondInterface">
    <bean class="com.company.B2Class" />
</service>
```

In my second blueprint file, I have:

```
<cm:property-placeholder persistent-id="com.company.settings" update-strategy="reload">
    <cm:default-properties>
        <cm:property name="myFlag"/>
    </cm:default-properties>
</cm:property-placeholder>

<reference id="myBean" interface="com.company.MyFirstInterface">
```

Assume that I want:

- `myBean` to refer to `b1` if and only if `myFlag` is `false`, and
- `myBean` to refer to `b2` if and only if `myFlag` is `true`.

Is this possible given the above configuration?  If so, what needs to be done to allow this to work?

**Note:** I would like to avoid adding additional properties.  It is not a death sentence if I *really* need to add one; I need a solution to this problem regardless of convenience. `myFlag` just happens to be an existing property in a production system so if I can get away with sticking with this one property (which is directly related to which bean should be picked), that would preferred.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else encounters this, let me post the solution we came up with.

**Create your two beans**

```
<bean id="b1" class="com.company.B1Class" />
<bean id="b2" class="com.company.B2Class" />
```

**Create a factory class**

```
public class MyFactoryClass {
    private boolean myFlag;
    private B1Class b1;
    private B2Class b2;

    public MyFactoryClass(boolean myFlag, B1Class b1, B2Class b2) {
        this.myFlag = myFlag;
        this.b1 = b1;
        this.b2 = b2;
    }

    public MyFirstInterface buildIt() {
        return myFlag ? b2 : b1;
    }
}
```

**Define the factory class as a bean and use it to select the class**

```
<bean id="myFactory" class="com.company.MyFactoryClass">
    <argument value="${myFlag}"/>
    <argument ref="b1"/>
    <argument ref="b2"/>
</bean>

<bean id="myBean" factory-ref="myFactory" factory-method="buildIt" />
<service id="myBean" interface="com.company.MyFirstInterface" />
```

**The full blueprints**

First Blueprint:

```
<cm:property-placeholder persistent-id="com.company.settings" update-strategy="reload">
    <cm:default-properties>
        <cm:property name="myFlag"/>
    </cm:default-properties>
</cm:property-placeholder>

<bean id="b1" class="com.company.B1Class" />
<bean id="b2" class="com.company.B2Class" />

<bean id="myFactory" class="com.company.MyFactoryClass">
    <argument value="${myFlag}"/>
    <argument ref="b1"/>
    <argument ref="b2"/>
</bean>

<bean id="myBean" factory-ref="myFactory" factory-method="buildIt" />
<service id="myBean" interface="com.company.MyFirstInterface" />
```

Second Blueprint:

```
<reference id="myBean" interface="com.company.MyFirstInterface" />
```